# no way to send gmail from amazon AWS ec2?

Tags: email, amazon-ec2, smtp, gmail

I use [nodemailer](https://github.com/andris9/Nodemailer) that works well on dev localhost, but found not working on my amazonAWS ec2 instance.

I have read

[Gmail SMTP is not working in ec2 instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21087564/gmail-smtp-is-not-working-in-ec2-instance)

*Because of the spam abuse that has historically been sent from people using EC2 instances, virtually ALL popular mail providers block the receipt of email from EC2 instances. The world of email and anti-spam measures is part-technical, part-political. For this reason, AWS offers Amazon Simple Email Service.*

No workaround? Is it just impossible to use gmail with ec2?

If impossible what is the easiest alternative method? thanks.

Comment: Just as a note, I've successfully relayed email via Gmail's SMTP domain in the past from EC2 Oregon (however, I don't know if the region is significant).

Comment: Thanks, perhaps, it's after your usage that Gmail block amazon ec2.

Answer (score 2):

The best 'work around' is to use SES for sending email from an ec2 instance. Unless you are sending huge amounts of email, the cost is insignificant.

If you 'verify' your gmail address thru SES, you can still send out emails that will look like they came from your gmail account, but actually sent by SES.

Comment: Thanks, now what I'm working on is to use GoogleAppengine for the gmail sender.