# Amazon Ec2 Postfix outgong mail for external domain is not working

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, postfix-mta, outgoing-mail

I have Amazon EC2 Linux instance where I have configured Postfix.

(1) Incoming mail from external work is working
(2) Outcoming mail with in domain is working
(3) Outgoing mail to exnter domain (Gmail, Yahoo) is not working

This is my main.cf configuration

I think I am missing something, I have west my two days, I have try various configuration options but not getting any right reason or error and solution

Error:

Aug  3 08:08:07 ip-10-0-0-7 postfix/smtp[10379]: DEE6A26ECD: to=, relay=smtp.mydomin.in[72.167.238.29]:25, delay=35, delays=34/0.01/0.83/0.39, dsn=4.1.1, status=SOFTBOUNCE (host smtp.mydomin.in[72.167.238.29] said: 550 5.1.1  Recipient not found.  http://x.co/irbounce (in reply to RCPT TO command))
A

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
default_destination_concurrency_limit = 4
home_mailbox = Maildir/
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mail_owner = postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost,$mydomain
mydomain = mydomin.in
myhostname = mydomin
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8  10.0.0.7 54.xxx.xxx.xxx
mynetworks_style = host
myorigin = $mydomain
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/README_FILES
recipient_delimiter = +
relay_domains = $mydomain
relayhost = smtp.mydomin.in
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
smtp_connection_cache_destinations = $relayhost
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/password
smtp_sasl_security_options =
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, check_recipient_access mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_recipient.
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
soft_bounce = yes
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
```

Comment: Nope; won't work.

Please see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21087564/gmail-smtp-is-not-working-in-ec2-instance/21096310#21096310

Answer (score 0):

In your main.cf, could you try to change

```
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8  10.0.0.7 54.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

to

```
mynetworks = all
```

Once done, don't forget to `reload / restart` postfix.

Comment: Is there any issue from my godaddy configuration?   My Error says :- (host smtp.mydomin.in[68.178.213.203] said: 550 5.1.1 <info.mydomin@gmail.com> Recipient not found.  <http://x.co/irbounce> (in reply to RCPT TO command))