# Meteor email sending issue

Tags: email, meteor

I have a Meteor App that I put on their new Galaxy Platform that throws this error when attempting to send a verification email.

```
Exception while invoking method 'sendEmailVerificationMessage' Error: Greeting never received

at Object.Future.wait (/app/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/future.js:398:15)
```

The Meteor people said that it's an issue with my App but it works just fine both on my testing server and when deployed to Modulus. When checking the email server it never shows any attempt to send email from Galaxy.

My question is, is there any further testing that I can do to see exactly what the problem is, maybe some debugging code that I can add to the code?

```
  process.env.MAIL_URL = 'smtp://' + encodeURIComponent(smtp.username)
  + ':' + encodeURIComponent(smtp.password) + '@'
  + encodeURIComponent(smtp.server) + ':25';
```

Comment: It is using our own SMTP server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It often hosting provider block SMTP server as it often being abused by user

First, check it with localhost. If it work, then probably Galaxy block SMTP server. Contact them for more info

**EDIT**

This work with me with Digital Ocean. Haven't test with Galaxy

```
/*Send Email Through Gmail SMTP*/
process.env.MAIL_URL="smtp://gmailUsername:gmailPassword@smtp.gmail.com:587";
```

**EDIT 2**

See here: [Gmail SMTP is not working in ec2 instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21087564/gmail-smtp-is-not-working-in-ec2-instance)

Galaxy use AWS EC2, so you should setup AWS SES. Free SMTP include gmail isn't work with AWS

Comment: They said last week that their "engineers" checked it out and everything on their end was fine.

Comment: Using a Gmail account the Galaxy server is not throwing that error. However after 10 minutes I still haven't receiver the activation email.

Comment: I'd rather not use Gmail for this app. I'll try to add EC2's entire IP range as trusted SMTP addresses.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that Galaxy uses AWS. Switched it to port 587 and working just fine. You think that would be something they know?

Comment: Glad it help. Port 587 is standard port for SMTP server. They should know this

Answer (score 1):

When I set my port to 587 it started working. I'm setting `process.env.MAIL_URL` inside `Meteor.startup()` for local/development and seeing no problems. Hope this helps someone!