# How do I use Gmail SMTP with port 587 on AWS EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, smtp, port, inbound-security-rule

I have used Gmail SMTP service with port 587 on the local server and it's working fine.

But it's not working on AWS EC2 instance. So I added SMTP rules on EC2 instance security inbound rules see below image but SMTP port can not be editable.

Now the issue is if your domain does not configure[image] secured connections. Gmail does not offer port 25 in an unsecured connection.

So, there is any way to use SMTP on unsecured connection with 25 port or any other way.

Comment: It is unclear what you are actually trying to accomplish here.  Are you trying to **send** email from EC2 using GMail credentials?  If that is not working, then how exactly does it fail?  Or are you trying to set up your server to accept incoming mail?

Comment: I'm trying to send email from EC2 using Gmail credentials and I used 587 port for Gmail SMTP. But AWS EC2 is allowed only 25 SMTP port. Now as per Google documents Gmail does not offer port 25 in an unsecured connection. So there is any other way to use 587 SMTP port on AWS EC2

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have fixed issue as of now for a development server. Please, not it's not the correct way to a production site.

For sending an email from AWS EC2 using Gmail SMTP service please follow below steps.

1. Edit security group of your EC2 Instance.
2. Edit inbound rules of the security group.
3. Add 587 port in inbound rules. See below image.

you need to set your instance inbound rules for coming mail and outbound for send.

[image]

After that, you can send email using 587 SMTP port from AWS EC2.

Please read this article. https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

Comment: it looks strange because inbound means "comming in" but sending is rather "comming out" which does not restrict by default. Does it means that you have installed software which listen 587 port?

Comment: I updated as shown, but still mails are not going out

Comment: Tried this but it isn't working. @Krupal Patel, could you please update you answer with the proper way around for sending email.

Comment: The reason for inbound is for handshaking. If email sending client doesn't hear back from the SMTP target, then the send will fail.

Answer (score 4):

Because of the spam abuse that has historically been sent from people using EC2 instances, virtually ALL popular mail providers block the receipt of email from EC2 instances. The world of email and anti-spam measures is part-technical, part-political. For this reason, AWS offers Amazon Simple Email Service.

Step to fix it-

1. Go to google account setting and Turn on Two-step verification.
2. Now generate an app password for the app you want to send mail.
3. Use the generated password for the app in SMTP with the same Email.

That's it.

Comment: How can we generate the app password?

Comment: @AnilKumar here you go- https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en

Answer (score 2):

To send email from C# hosted on Amazon EC2, make sure you have two things done.

1. Use following setting in your Web.config

> ```
> <mailSettings>
>       <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="<from email goes here>">
>         <network host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587" enableSsl="true" userName="email id goes here" password="<password goes here> />   
>       </smtp>
>     </mailSettings>
> ```

2. Login the above gmail account onto the Amazon EC2. If you do not login, then gmail blocks the email being sent from code due to security reasons.

Comment: How can we login to gmail from EC2. Where is the option?

Comment: On my EC2 instance, I simply logged into my Gmail account through Chrome and that did the trick for me.

Comment: @AnilKumar You simply login using the browser on the EC2 and this should then work.

Answer (score 1):

According to Googles documentation, you can use the G Suite SMTP relay service through port 25. You can read more information here:

https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en

and here:

https://support.google.com/a/answer/2956491

Hope this helps!

Comment: Gmail does not offer port 25 in an unsecured connection. For use port 25 secure connection are required as per gmail "Configuration requirements"
https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en

Comment: No matter what AWS SAYS it does, in fact port 25 is blocked regardless of your EC2 security settings and it is nearly impossible to get AWS to unblock it for your instance. They really, really want you to send mail through SES and no reason you give is good enough for them to give you a waiver/exception.