# I can not send Email(Gmail) with Django on AWS

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, apache, amazon-ec2

I upload a Web app created by Django(with Apache2) to AWS.
I can send Emails from a Form on Ubuntu, but I can not on AWS EC2 and Server Error(500) occurs even if I use the same codes.

If I send Email with python manage.py shell_plus, I can send Email.

```
[ec2-user@]$ python manage.py shell_plus
>>> from django.core.mail import send_mail
>>> send_mail(mail_subject, mail_message, mail_from, mail_to, fail_silently=False,)
```

But I cannot from the Django Web app.

What should I do to send Email as Gmail? Or should I use Amazon SES instead?

Thanks.

settings.py

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = "django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend"
EMAIL_HOST = "smtp.gmail.com"
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ.get("GMAIL_HOST_USER")
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get("GMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD")
EMAIL_FROM_EMAIL = os.environ.get("GMAIL_HOST_EMAIL")
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

I added Inbound Rule(EC2)

```
port:587  IPv4:0.0.0.0
```

Django 4.1.7
Python 3.8.16
Apache 2.4.56
mod_wsgi 4.9.4

Comment: _But I cannot from the Django Web app_ What do you mean you "cannot"?  What happens when you try?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. When I tried, just displayed Server Error(500) on Browser. I read `/etc/httpd/logs/error_log`, but nothing was written about the failure of sending Gmail.

Comment: You may be able to work around this issue by turning on [2FA in Gmail and enabling app passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63043473).

Comment: Thank you.  I had already done the 2FA. After I read the page you linked and understood what I tried to do was difficult, I understood Google does not want people to do what I tried to do.